# Jquery only works with breakpoint

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-tabs, breakpoints

I am using the following code to follow named anchors in jquery-ui-tabs.  I have it so when the link is clicked it is supposed to take me to the appropriate tab and scroll to the id.  The linking works (after much ado), however the scroll is only working if I put a breakpoint on the animate line.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('a[goto]').click(function(evt) {
        evt.preventDefault();
        var whereTo = $(this).attr('goto');
        $tabs = $("ul.ui-tabs-nav li");
        $tabs.find('a[href=#' + whereTo + ']').trigger('click')
        $('html,body').animate({
            scrollTop:$(this.hash).offset().top},
            500);
        });
    }); 
});
```

I tried making it part of a callback, but still no luck.

```
 $('a[goto]').click(function(evt) {
     evt.preventDefault();
     var whereTo = $(this).attr('goto');
     $tabs = $("ul.ui-tabs-nav li");
     $tabs.find('a[href=#' + whereTo + ']').trigger('click', function(){
         $('html,body').animate({scrollTop:$(this.hash).offset().top}, 500);
     });
 });
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Where have you read that trigger method accepts a function?

Comment: Nowhere, I just read that callbacks are usually the way to handle the breakpoint problem.  What shoud I be doing?

Comment: What is "the breakpoint problem"?

Comment: I was referring to when the code works correctly, but only with a breakpoint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`trigger` method doesn't accept a callback function, it triggers the event so that event handler is executed, you have the value using `goto` attributes, what you are trying to do finally gives you the value of  this variable, <strike>actually that part is redundant.</strike> Simply use `whereTo` variable.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
  var $tabs = $("ul.ui-tabs-nav li");
  $('a[goto]').click(function (evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    var whereTo = $(this).attr('goto');
    var hash = this.hash;
    // 1
    $tabs.find('a[href=#' + whereTo + ']').trigger('click');
    setTimeout(function(){
       $('html,body').animate({
          scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top
       }, 500);
    }, 500)
    // 2
    // $tabs.find('a[href=#' + whereTo + ']').trigger('click')
    // $('#'+ whereTo).closest('.ui-tabs-panel').promise().done(function(){
    //     $('html,body').animate({
    //        scrollTop: $('#' + whereTo).offset().top
    //     }, 500);
    // })
  });
});
```

Note that `goto` is not valid attribute, if you are using HTML5 consider using `data-*` attributes.

Comment: I had something similar before I tried the callback (though I need that trigger to switch tabs0.  I think the scroll isn't working because it's executing before the tab switches.  Updated the original post to reflect both

Comment: "actually that part is redundant", unless the tab has one or more 'click' handlers attached, which need to be triggered, eg, panel swapping.

Comment: I may not have specified, but the target content is in a different tab.

Comment: @orion4567 Okay, so at first tab's content should be visible, right?

Comment: Right, the first content's tab is visble.  The link is in the tab content.  When I click the link it is taking me to the correct tab, but will not scroll to the correct element unless I set a breakpoint on the animate function.

Comment: @orion4567 Yes, that's because it should wait untill content will be visible, it's a bit hackish but try my updated answer with `setTimeout`.

Comment: @undefined, how about temporarily attaching a namespaced 'click' handler for the scroll animation, and removing it when the animation is complete?

Comment: @Beetroot-Beetroot I don't think that can solve the issue, promise works only if animation of the element that is getting animated is complete, I should have selected that element, I think now the second method will work.

Comment: A couple of notes:  whereTo does not work for the scroll variable because it takes you to the top of the page.  I tried to go back to hash but is was not working inside of the timeout.  I wound up setting a variable with this.hash before the timeout function was called and then referencing that